# Why "\n" is not interpreted in "go to the new line" into the HTML page?

Tags: javascript

I send from javascript to the server (Java) a string with ajax call like this:

```
"I'm writing a (here a pressed enter key button) text"
```

To the server arrive this:

```
"I'm writing a \n text"
```

Enter key button it has been translated in the \n.

Now, from the server, a resend the same string to HTML into a popup.
This is what it is displayed:

```
"I'm writing a \n text"
```

\n is not interpreted to "go to the new line".

Why?

**UPDATE**

This is the code:

```
message = "I'm writing a \n text";
...
<div id="popuè"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #1d5987;">'+message+'</span></div>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you're using.

Comment: It does not, and never has done so, in HTML. (Perhaps you could use `<br/>` there. Just a guess.)

Comment: @Jongware, But it is a string, not code. If a replace \n to the <br/> into a string it is displayed a <br/> anyway.

Comment: If the `\n` appears *literally* in the popup, something in between may be 'parsing' your string into proper HTML. That would also explain the translation of entities into literal text.

Comment: @Jongware, I have updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Because `\n` is not valid html and will not be read by the parser. You need to put `<br/>` instead

Comment: But it is a string, not code. If a replace \n to the <br/> into a string it is displayed a <br/> anyway.

Comment: You need to edit your original question and show your current code

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle it from the server?

```
server_response.replace(/\\n/, '<br/>');
```

ASCII is not HTML after all.

Comment: But it is a string, not code. If a replace \n to the <br/> into a string it is displayed a <br/> anyway.